# fWrite overwrites the whole file?

Tags: php

me again, this time with a PHP question... I'm busy making some sort of admin panel (Really basic) but when I'm trying to change like my slider or something the fwrite overwrites EVERYTHING. This is my PHP code:

```
 <?php 
          $errorsslider = array();
          if($_POST['slider']){
              $slider_site = $_POST['slider'];
           $f=fopen("../app/includes/configfunctions.php","w");

   $set_slider = 
   "<?php
    DEFINE('slider', " . $_POST['slider'] . ");
     ";
  if (fwrite($f,$set_slider)>0){
   fclose($f);

  }
  $errorsslider[] = "<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button>" . $LANG['admin']['global']['SliderSuccess']; "</div>";
        return $errorsslider;
          }
  ?>
```

So before I run this, this is my file:

```
<?php
DEFINE('slider', false);
DEFINE('login', true);
?>
```

and after I runned it, this is my file:

```
<?php
DEFINE('slider', false);
?>
```

Does anyone have a solution?

P.S. Don't mind the code, looks ugly, I know...

Lisa

Comment: if you dont want to overwrite the file then change the file opening mode into `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation of [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) specifies `w` being:

> **'w'**
>   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Hence your file is completely replaced every time. If you want to *append* to the file, open it with `a` instead (`fopen($file, 'a')`):

> **'a'**
>   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: But then it'll go to the bottom of the file. I want it to replace line 2 `DEFINE('slider', false);` still, thanks for the answer, learned another thing today!

Comment: @LisaW May I suggest that you use another format than defines? You could use a JSON file to save the data and define the variables when loading the JSON file.